# Issue with publishing API Product to Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I am using **API Connect: v5.0.5.0** (apiconnect: v2.4.11) Developer toolkit on Windows 10. I am able to publish my *loopback* application to *Bluemix* successfully from the *Developer Toolkit*. However, while trying to publish/stage corresponding *API Product* to my Bluemix API Connect instance from *APIC Developer toolkit*  is getting the following exception.

[image]

I would like to know where to find additional message (as indicated in the error )and any tips or suggestion to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you're having problems publishing I'd suggest running `apic validate` against your product file first to see if there are any validation issues.

I grabbed your product/api files from the developer.ibm.com question and did some testing. I found that your path `/containers/{container}/download/{file}` has two parameters defined as

`parameters:
        - name: container
          in: path
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: file
          in: path
          required: false
          type: string`

By no means am I an expert in this space, but I found if I change `required: false` to `required: true` validation was successful. Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

[Arindam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6175236/arindam-chattopadhya),
I have seen this issue before. This solved my issue. Scroll down to answer by Peter Szeto.

http://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/268185/api-designer-cant-publish-loopback-project/?smartspace=api

Comment: I already tried the suggestion from Peter. I don't have any type: file in API Source